# Underlayment (vapor, moisture and sound abatement) under marble tile floors

Tags: flooring, tile, underlayment, marble

Do you use an underlayment (vapor, moisture and sound abatement) on top of concrete subfloors and **under marble tile flooring**? Ultimately the marble will not be installed using traditional mudding methods. The marble tile will be glued to (possibly) the top of the underlayment. My condo building states that I must have an underlayment however, all of the products I'm researching do not say anything about or refer to marble tile flooring, only hardwood and laminate flooring.